# Does that means that I have horizontal margins 1in as well?

Tags: margins, overleaf

In my code, I am using the following line:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=1in]{geometry}
```

Does that means that I have horizontal margins 1in as well? I do not know exactly what are the default settings of an $A_4$ paper.

Comment: No. If you want all margins to be 1in, use the key `margin=1in`.

Comment: you can see all values in the log-file. And the geometry documentation describes how they are calculated.

Comment: you do not want 1in horizontal margins if using 10pt fonts on A4 paper unless you want to make your line lengths impossibly long to read. Have some thought for your readers.

Comment: @Bernard can you please tell me the context of margin=1in , where should I put it?

Comment: Sorry if that is a trivial question but what do you mean by log-file?@UlrikeFischer

Comment: In the the  place of `vmargin=1in`, when you koad geometry. As to the log file, it is one of the auxiliary files produced by the compiler.